# estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id rest call return null in magento

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-methods, ups

I am working on to create a custom UPS Shipping method, I have integrated and get price from ups api and set shipping price. But, while click `ship here` the shipping method  loads, then hang the browser.

I checked browser network, it taks log time to load this rest call `http://127.0.0.1/magento217/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id` and return null value in magento 2.

Its only happen Ups shipping is enable, other shipping methods fine.

Suggest Me, Why its take long time to load.

**Note:** I have disable Magento 2 default Ups Shipping method via `config.php`.